# How to unit test an HttpClient (HttpMessageHandler) with Moq based on the URL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpclient, moq

To Devs,
I would be mocking HttpMessageHandler to test an HttpClient, my question is how would I mock based on the
URL and Http Method?  So the response would be a function of the Method and URL:

```
Get + "http://testdoc.com/run?test=true&t2=10   => return X
Get + "http://testdoc.com/walk?test=true&t2=10   => return Y
Post + "http://testdoc.com/walk   => return Z
```

All 3 calls would return something different.

My current unit test catches everything:

```
var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
    {  ... });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling the moq setup to use any http request message with: `ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()`, so for any instance of `HttpRequestMessage` it will always return the same outcome.

If you a different X outcomes, you will need to create X different instances:

```
string firstUri = "http://testdoc.com/run?test=true&t2=10";
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage_1 = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri(firstUri),
    Method = ...,
    Content = ...,
};
```

And instead of `ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()` is that instance of `httpRequestMessage_1`, with:

```
.Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", httpRequestMessage_1, ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
.ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
{  /* Something with X */ });
```

Comment: Multiple mocks for multiple test cases, will try a specific Request Message and see if the values are checked. You answered it, thanks.

Comment: Happy it helped you

Answer (score 4):

Based on your code I came up with the code below
that mocks two different calls recognised by their URL.

```
var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

var content = new HttpContentMock(usersQueryResult);
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

mockMessageHandler.Protected()
  .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
    "SendAsync",
    ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(rm => 
      rm.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://example.com/api/users?query=")),
    ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(
      new HttpResponseMessage
      {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Content = content
      };
    );

mockMessageHandler.Protected()
  .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
    "SendAsync",
    ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(rm => 
      rm.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://example.com/api/users/gurka/")),
    ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
  .ReturnsAsync(
    new HttpResponseMessage
    {
      StatusCode = 201,
      Content = null, // In reality the user found but we don't care for this test.
    }
  );
}

private class HttpContentMock : HttpContent
{
  private readonly IList<AdUserDataContract> users;
  public HttpContentMock(IList<AdUserDataContract> users)
  {
    this.users = users;  }

  protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
  {
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(users, typeof(AdUsersDataContract));
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
  {
    length = 1; // Well... not totally true is it?
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution! I used this to solve a problem that I got 90% there using SetupSequence() but needed the Callback() method to interrogate the request for an id value that needed to be in the response (SOAP). After two days, it is now working.